# Upgrading PHP version in Matomo on Ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu, matomo

I have Matomo installed on my server using php@7.4.33.

In order to remove the warning showing in Matomo dashboard I want to upgrade to php8.2 only on Matomo directory, without affecting the system.

[image: warningInMatomo]

I was wondering about how to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can run two php-fpm processes one for 7.4 and one for 8.2 and proxy_pass requests to the required one based on the location.

Comment: Thanks for your response,
As I mentioned, I'm running php7.4, should I also run 7.4 php-fpm version ?
Or should I just add 8.2 php-fpm ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/671400/multiple-versions-of-php-through-nginx

Comment: This is exactly what I did, and it worked.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-multiple-php-versions-on-one-server-using-apache-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-20-04
Thanks a lot